# How is $r(\theta) = \sin \frac\theta2$ symmetric about the x-axis?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, symmetry

I understand how it is symmetric about the $y$-axis.

because $r(-\theta) = \sin \left(-\frac\theta2\right)=-\sin \left(\frac\theta2\right)=-r(\theta)$

But how is it symmetric about $x$-axis?

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$r(\pi+\theta)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+\frac\theta2\right)=\cos\frac\theta2$$
$$r(\pi-\theta)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\frac\theta2\right)=\cos\frac\theta2$$

Alternatively, $r(-\theta)=-r(\theta)$, hence your $y$-axis symmetry, but you have also $$r(2\pi-\theta)=\sin\left(\pi-\frac\theta2\right)=\sin\frac\theta2=r(\theta)$$
$$r(2\pi+\theta)=\sin\left(\pi+\frac\theta2\right)=-\sin\frac\theta2=-r(\theta)$$

Hence the points associated to angles $\theta$, $-\theta$, $2\pi-\theta$, $2\pi+\theta$ form a rectangle.

Comment: So the points (r , pi-theta) and (r, pi+theta ) are equal ? how does that imply the symmetry about the x-axis ?   shouldn't it be - r = sin ( pi - (theta/2)) ??

Comment: @Knytr Make a drawing, and it will become very clear ;-) If you prefer, consider $r(\theta)$ and $r(2\pi-\theta)$.

Comment: i actually did the drawing but the questions that i am trying to solve wants to identify the symmetries THEN do the drawing. i tried the point (-r , pi-theta) but all i got was sin(Theta/2) (which isn't equal to - r ) .

Comment: @Knytr Making a drawing of the angles is just to help visualize what happens. Also, you should always write the angle when you write $r$, or you will get lost easily. Now, consider angles $-\theta$ and $2\pi-\theta$, that is, $r(-\theta)$ and $r(2\pi-\theta)$. Maybe easier this way. Notice these two angles are along the same geometric "ray", but the sign of $r$ is opposite. So? Another hint: you can complete the rectangle: take angles $\theta$, $-\theta$, $2\pi-\theta$, $2\pi+\theta$.

Comment: oh wow , i see .. when i plugged (2pi-theta) i got why it is symmetric about the x-axis. the problem is in the book i use only uses the points (r,-theta) and (-r,pi-theta ) to identify the symmetry so thats why i was confused . Thank you very much